# Cannot declare instance of a class in another due to error "cannot be referenced from static context."

Tags: java, class, instantiation

My code below has an issue at `Activity activity = new Activity();`
Nothing I have found is exactly similar to this issue. I have a basic private class in my main that I am trying to instance and it is not letting me.Removing Static from the method main definition makes he error go away however the code won't compile because the static definition is necessary. Any advice on what changes are needed?

```
public class Main
{
    public class Activity
    {
        public int start;
        public int finish;
        public String name;
    }

    private Activity[] activityArray;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 0, endTime = 0, i = 0;


        try
        {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("activities.txt"));
            try
            {

                Activity[] activityArray = new Activity[10];
                String line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null)
                {

******              Activity activity = new Activity();

                    String[] activityString = line.split(",");

                    if(activityString.length == 2)
                    {
                        endTime = Integer.parseInt(activityString[0]);
                        n = Integer.parseInt(activityString[1]);
                        activityArray = new Activity[n];

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //System.out.println(activityString.length);
                        activity.setStart(Integer.parseInt(activityString[1]));
                        activity.setFinish(Integer.parseInt(activityString[2]));
                        activity.setName(activityString[0]);
                        activityArray[i] = activity;
                        i++;
                    }
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {}finally
            {
                br.close();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nesetd `Activity` class is an instance-specific class (aka an "inner class"). To make it available from code in a static context, you need to make it a static nested class:

```
public static class Activity
```

More about the difference in [this standard Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Comment: Did not know there was such a thing as static in class names. But thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @WorthAShot: Only for nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

The class `Activity` is an *inner* class, which means a non-static nested class. Inner classes can only be created in association to an instance of the surrounding class.

You need to define it as a *static* nested class. This makes it available without an instance of the surrounding class, so it can be used in static contexts.

Answer (score 0):

It is because if you want to create an instance of an inner class object, it basically creates for that particular "this" instance of the class. this is not accessible in static context as static is.not bound to any instance.

If you still want to achieve it without making it static,

```
Activity activityObj = new Main().new Activity();
```

Hope this helps.